# GCP - Find which projects are being used and which projects are empty and not used

Tags: google-cloud-platform, project, legacy

I have old Google cloud platform projects that we aren't sure for 100% that are not being used.

We have checked the API usage, and activity, but is it enough?
What checks do you do to verify you can delete it?

Answer (score 4):

API usages and logs are the good places.

In addition, you can also check the most important resources and backup them to be sure that no one use them.

Eventually, and in the worst case, you can undelete a project within the 30 days after the deletion, if you missed something wand want to rollback the deletion.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually a sound advice. I *was* hoping for a gcloud command, but this is as good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GCP Cloud recommender for that:
https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/google-cloud-launches-unattended-project-recommender

The tool will give you all you need to take decisions around project deletion.

To enable Recommemder:

> gcloud services enable recommender.googleapis.com --project=$id

It can be a folder or an organization too. Then, run Recommender:

> gcloud recommender recommendations list --project=PROJECT_ID --location=global --recommender=google.resourcemanager.projectUtilization.Recommender

Again the scope and recommendations can be any.

Hope it helps!